# jqGrid Custom Search Template

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 5.1.1

I'm attempting to use custom search filer to display in what I "request" in gTmpl, but it doesn't show me anything but default ones.

my gTmpl will always be different based on the GRID for certain data to be pulled, so this is one of few examples:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    datatype:'json',jsonReader:{repeatitems:false},loadonce:true,jqModal:false,
    viewrecords:true,altRows:true,hoverrows:false,hidegrid:false,
    rowNum:500,rowList:[100,250,500,1000,2000,3000],autowidth:true,pager:'#InfViewP',
    recordtext:'{0}/{2} Rec',emptyrecords:'No Rec Found',loadtext:'Loading...'
});

var gTmpl = {groupOp:'OR',rules:[{'field':'userName','op':'cn','data':''},{'field':'CityName','op':'cn','data':''}]};

        $('#InfView').jqGrid({
            url:url,
            colModel:[
                {label:'Player',name:'userName'},
                {label:'City',name:'CityName',align:'right',width:350}
            ]
        });

$('#InfView').navGrid('#InfViewP',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{},gTmpl,{top:54,left:50,caption:'Search - Overview'});
```

I do not want to use tmplNames or tmplFilers (if at all possible).  Is there any way around it?  Lastly, without gTmpl, the search dialog would be properly located on browser, but when I have gTmpl in, the {top,left,caption...} is ignored and placed at 0,0.

Unless I have the parameters wrong, please do let me know..  Thanks!

Comment: I think that there is exist misunderstanding about the terminology. You write about "Custom Search Template" and "custom search filer", but I think that you use wrong words because your wrote additionally that you "do not want to use tmplNames or tmplFilers". Do you want to display the filter `{groupOp:'OR',rules:[{'field':'userName','op':'cn','data':''},{'field':'CityName','op':'cn','data':''}]}` **on the first opening the Searching Dialog only or you have another goals?

Comment: You're probably right on misunderstanding on terminology since that's how I read it haha... yes using display based on filter I stated.  How would I go about that?  I just didn't want the drop down menu on Filter (Default, Custom), just wanted it to load those immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to implement is displaying the specified filter on the first opening of the searching dialog. Do do this you should first specify `postData.filters` and seconds to use `multipleSearch:true` and optionally `multipleGroup:true` as the searching option:

```
var myInitialFilter = {
        groupOp:'OR',
        rules: [
            {'field':'userName','op':'cn','data':''},
            {'field':'CityName','op':'cn','data':''}
        ]
    };

$('#InfView').jqGrid({
    url:url,
    colModel:[
        {label:'Player',name:'userName'},
        {label:'City',name:'CityName',align:'right',width:350}
    ],
    postData: {
        filters: myInitialFilter
    }
});

$('#InfView').navGrid('#InfViewP',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{},
    {multipleSearch:true, top:54, left:50, caption:'Search - Overview'});
```

Additionally I would recommend you to consider to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead of commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the current prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop and which can be used completely free of charge. It's compatible to jqGrid 4.7 (which features you use currently).

Free jqGrid has many new features, which can be helpful in some scenarios. For example, you load the data from the server and use `loadonce: true` option. It means that the server have to return *sorted data*. Free jqGrid has new option `forceClientSorting: true`, which can be used together with `loadonce: true` option. It force *initial sorting on the client side*. If you would add `search: true` option and would specify `postData.filter`, like in the above example, then the data returned from the server will be filtered and sorted **locally** before the first page of the data will be displayed. The user will be still able to change the filter and to display all the data.

Comment: Alrighty!  Converting from 5.1.1 to Free jqGrid 4.9.2 and will let ya know how that go shortly :)

Comment: Oh i can DEFINITELY say free jqGrid is ALOT better, more flexibility, I'm still working on tweaking few parameters, the autowidth are giving me headache, but I'm getting there... meantime, gonna give THUMBS UP on the custom filtering.. works like charm!

Comment: Ok here is the width issue, all i got at the moment for width are: autowidth:auto, nothing else (everything else at default parameters), as you can see in both image:

This image shows that the column is overlapping the scrollbar column:
http://prntscr.com/crlz2x

This image, the column is not resizing (no width is set for the first column, only 2nd column at 22px:
http://prntscr.com/crlzmy

The only quick "fix" is when I resize my browser, then they all are back to normal..

Comment: @sgkdnay: Please use always *the latest* version of free jqGrid. The last released version is 4.13.4. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases or better, use it from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). The current code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid): jqGrid 4.13.5-pre 2016-10-07 is stable enough too. I'll publish it soon as the version 4.13.5.

Comment: @sgkdnay: The problem, which you explain should not exist in the latest version, but you can explicitly call `$('#InfView')[0].fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding();` too. It tests whether the vertical scroll bars already exist and adjust `"padding-left` (or `padding-right`) to improve the visibility of the grid to fix the problem, which you describes. If the problem will be not fixed after the usage of free jqGrid 4.13.4, then please provide the demo, which I could use to reproduce the problem and to fix it.

Comment: I might have to start using CDN link, I always like to have the file locally on the server.  The version I have is 4.13.3pre.  I'll do CDN first and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @sgkdnay: Where you get the version 4.13.3pre? Why you get it? 4.13.3pre means just some intermediate version between 4.13.2 and 4.13.3. You wrote that you used 5.1.1 before. Why you get some undefined state of free jqGrid instead of the usage of some release? You should update to the 4.13.4 or the latest jqGrid 4.13.5-pre 2016-10-07. I wrote you before that I can help you to fix the problem only if it's still exist in the current version (4.13.4 or the latest code loaded from GitHub via RawGit). Only if the problem isn't already fixed I need the demo, which I reproduces the problem.

Comment: @sgkdnay: It doesn't matter how you will use free jqGrid *finally*. One need to make *one test only* to verify whether the problem exist in the current version of free jqGrid. You need just change (**temporary**) 3 lines of your HTML code to load free jqGrid from CDN or RawGit (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). It's very simple test with which one should always start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125296/discussion-between-sgkdnay-and-oleg).